# Error with matrix operation on python

Tags: python, numpy

I am a little new to python programming with data sciences.
X is a matrix 97x2 elements, theta is a 3x1 element vector, y a 97X2 vector
m= length of y=97
Following is the algorithm in python but I am not getting where is the mistake.

```
J= (1/2*m)*sum(np.square(np.dot(X,theta)-y)))
```

I have to element wise multiplication and sum them up to get one scalar value J(cost function). However I am getting an array of 97 elements of 0

Comment: python 2 or python 3?

Answer (score 0):

First of all this would not run with dimensions provided. `np.dot(A, B)` requires A and B to match on one dimension, and yours are 97x2 and 3x1, thus it makes no sense. Probably the algorithm you are trying to implement requires you to concatenate a columns of 1s to X (as it looks like regular linear regression). Second of all division that you use is **integer division** in python 2 which will cause 0s to appear when you do stuff like `1/2 *` it is actually equivalent to `0 *`. Simply cast your variables to floats, thus do

```
J = (0.5*m)*sum(np.square(np.dot(X, theta) - y)))
```